# Django count records by different criteria

Tags: django, django-queryset

Django 1.8+, Python 3.4+

I want to perform a query over a certain set of records, counting them by different criteria.

Actual SQL query I'm aiming to achieve:

```
select count(*),
       sum(case when type=1 then 1 else 0 end),
       sum(case when total > 1000 then 1 else 0 end)
  from mytable
 where conditions
```

Is it possible to define this query in django or do I have to do multiple `.filter().count()` calls?

Comment: You should have a look at https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/db/aggregation/#cheat-sheet .

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to [ilse2005](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1762988/ilse2005), I managed to dig through the documentation.

A QuerySet matching my desired query goes like this:

```
MyTable.objects.aggregate(
    total=Count('id'),
    responses=Sum(Case(When(type=1, then=1), default=0, output_field=IntegerField())),
    big_ones=Sum(Case(When(total__gt=1000, then=1), default=0, output_field=IntegerField()))
)
```